# Duplicated classes - Unity - Android

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

The point is that Im doing a Project in Unity that combines VR and AR in the same mobile application.

When I try to compile the program I get the next error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/al315149/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Application;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$AudioStats;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$Capture;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$Share;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$ShareStart;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$View;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$DoublePrecisionTransform;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:615)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:313)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runDx(Main.java:291)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:247)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:607)
    ... 9 more
]
stdout[
ignored resource C:\Users\al315149\Desktop\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr-keyboard\libs\.\armeabi-v7a\libgvr_keyboard_shim_unity.so
processing archive C:\Users\al315149\Desktop\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr-keyboard\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource com/google/vr/keyboard/
processing com/google/vr/keyboard/BuildConstants.class...
processing com/google/vr/keyboard/GvrKeyboardLoaderClient.class...
processing com/google/vr/keyboard/GvrKeyboardLoaderClient$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/keyboard/GvrKeyboardLoaderClient$KeyboardContextWrapper.class...
processing com/google/vr/keyboard/GvrKeyboardUnity.class...
processing com/google/vr/keyboard/IGvrKeyboardLoader.class...
processing com/google/vr/keyboard/IGvrKeyboardLoader$Stub.class...
processing com/google/vr/keyboard/IGvrKeyboardLoader$Stub$Proxy.class...
processing archive C:\Users\al315149\Desktop\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr-keyboardsupport-release\libs\.\classes.jar...
processing com/google/gvr/keyboardsupport/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/google/gvr/keyboardsupport/KeyboardFragment.class...
processing com/google/gvr/keyboardsupport/KeyboardFragment$1.class...
processing com/google/gvr/keyboardsupport/KeyboardFragment$KeyboardCallback.class...
processing com/google/gvr/keyboardsupport/TransitionVRActivity.class...
processing archive C:\Users\al315149\Desktop\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr-permissionsupport-release\libs\.\classes.jar...
processing com/google/gvr/permissionsupport/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/google/gvr/permissionsupport/PermissionsFragment.class...
processing com/google/gvr/permissionsupport/PermissionsFragment$1.class...
processing com/google/gvr/permissionsupport/PermissionsFragment$PermissionsCallback.class...
processing com/google/gvr/permissionsupport/TransitionVRActivity.class...
processing com/google/gvr/permissionsupport/TransitionVRActivity$1.class...
ignored resource C:\Users\al315149\Desktop\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr\libs\.\armeabi-v7a\libgvr.so
processing archive C:\Users\al315149\Desktop\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\CarConfigurator\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr\libs\.\classes.jar...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Application.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$AudioStats.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$Capture.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$Share.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$ShareStart.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$View.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$DoublePrecisionTransform.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr$Actor.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr$Actor$ControllerState.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr$AppState.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr$ControllerState.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr$Environment.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr$Menu.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr$Preferences.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr$SplashScreen.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr$Tour.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr$Tutorial.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EarthVr$View.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EmbedVrWidget.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EmbedVrWidget$Pano.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EmbedVrWidget$Video.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$GConfigUpdate.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$GConfigUpdate$GConfigValue.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$HeadMount.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$HistogramBucket.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$JumpInspector.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$JumpInspector$AudioDetails.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$JumpInspector$ImageDetails.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$JumpInspector$ImagePlaybackDetails.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$JumpInspector$MediaDetails.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$JumpInspector$PickerDetails.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$JumpInspector$PlaybackDetails.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$JumpInspector$Resolution.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$JumpInspector$SphericalMetadata.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$JumpInspector$VideoDetails.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$JumpInspector$VideoPlaybackDetails.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Keyboard.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Keyboard$KeyboardEvent.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Keyboard$KeyboardTextEntry.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Launcher.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Lullaby.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Lullaby$LoadTime.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$PerformanceStats.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Photos.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Photos$OpenMedia.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Photos$WarmWelcome.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$QrCodeScan.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Renderer.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$SdkConfigurationParams.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$SdkConfigurationParams$AsyncReprojectionConfig.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$SensorStats.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$SensorStats$GyroscopeStats.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$SensorStats$Vector3.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$StreetView.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$StreetView$PanoSession.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$TimeSeriesData.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$TimeSeriesData$TimeIntervalData.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Transform.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$VrCore.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$VrCore$Controller.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$VrHome.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$VrHome$DialogAction.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$VrHome$GetViewerClick.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$VrHome$Setup.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$VrHome$Setup$StepStateChange.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$VrHome$Setup$View.class...
processing com/google/vr/audio/DeviceInfo.class...
processing com/google/vr/audio/DeviceInfo$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/audio/DeviceInfo$HeadphoneState.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/AndroidNCompat.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/AndroidNCompat$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/AndroidNCompat$2.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/AndroidNCompat$3.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/CardboardGLSurfaceView.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/CardboardGLSurfaceView$DetachListener.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ConfigUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ContentProviderVrParamsProvider.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ContextUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/DisplaySynchronizer.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/DisplayUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/EglFactory.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/EglReadyListener.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ExternalSurfaceManager.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ExternalSurfaceManager$ExternalSurface.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ExternalSurfaceManager$ExternalSurface$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ExternalSurfaceManager$ExternalSurfaceCallback.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ExternalSurfaceManager$ExternalSurfaceCallback$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ExternalSurfaceManager$ExternalSurfaceCallback$2.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ExternalSurfaceManager$ExternalSurfaceData.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/FrameMonitor.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/FullscreenMode.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/FullscreenMode$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/FullscreenMode$1$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/LegacyVrParamsProvider.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/MutableEglConfigChooser.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/NFCUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/NFCUtils$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/PackageUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/PhoneParams.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/PhoneParams$PpiOverride.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ScanlineRacingRenderer.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ScanlineRacingRenderer$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ScreenOrientationDetector.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ScreenOrientationDetector$Listener.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ScreenOrientationDetector$Orientation.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/StoragePermissionUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ThreadUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$2.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$3.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$4.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$5.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$TransitionListener.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$10.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$11.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$2.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$3.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$4.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$5.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$6.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$7.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$8.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$9.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiUtils$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiUtils$2.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiUtils$3.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiUtils$4.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UsedByNative.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/VrContextWrapper.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/VrCoreLibraryLoader.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/VrParamsProvider.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/VrParamsProviderFactory.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/VrParamsProviderFactory$ContentProviderClientHandle.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/VrParamsProviderJni.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/VrSettingsProviderContract.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/annotations/UsedByNative.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/annotations/UsedByReflection.class...
processing com/google/vr/internal/controller/NativeCallbacks.class...
processing com/google/vr/internal/controller/ServiceBridge.class...
processing com/google/vr/internal/controller/ServiceBridge$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/internal/controller/ServiceBridge$2.class...
processing com/google/vr/internal/controller/ServiceBridge$3.class...
processing com/google/vr/internal/controller/ServiceBridge$Callbacks.class...
processing com/google/vr/ndk/base/AndroidCompat.class...
processing com/google/vr/ndk/base/BufferSpec.class...
processing com/google/vr/ndk/base/BufferSpec$ColorFormat.class...
processing com/google/vr/ndk/base/BufferSpec$DepthStencilFormat.class...
processing com/google/vr/ndk/base/BufferViewport.class...
processing com/google/vr/ndk/base/BufferViewport$EyeType.class...
processing com/google/vr/ndk/base/BufferViewport$Reprojection.class...
processing com/google/vr/ndk/base/BufferViewportList.class...
processing com/google/vr/ndk/base/BuildConstants.class...
processing com/google/vr/ndk/base/BuildFlags.class...
processing com/google/vr/ndk/base/CardboardEmulator.class...<message truncated>
```

I have been looking for info and I have found that the problem is that those files are duplicated in some librarys:

```
Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent;
Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Application;
Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$AudioStats;
Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops;
Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$Capture;
Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$Share;
Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$ShareStart;
Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$View;
Lcom/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$DoublePrecisionTransform;
```

I've tried to open the duplicated classes into the .jar files and do a new .jar. The point is that the error continues appearing and when I go to the .jar files that I've created they have the deleted classes. I don't know if they are being overwritten by other program or I'm doing it badly but I'll love if someone could help me because I'm really frustrated at this moment.

Comment: did you found any solution?